# Application Main menu missing after quiting Blender

Tags: interface

I've been having a issue on my MacBook pro running OSx 10.11.5 where after I quit Blender the Main Menu at the top of my screen is missing. Has anybody else ever had this issue? I have waited up to 5 minutes in case it was some processor issue but it never comes back. I use the menu to quit Blender and it never comes back as if the Finder Application is not updating the menu. Any ideas?

Comment: Either a bug that needs to be reported or a configuration issue.